# Sending mail via Office 365 smtp using Invantive SQL

Tags: email, invantive-sql, invantive-data-hub

I'm trying to send a e-mail using the Invantive Data Hub using the following query (password and username are redacted).

```
insert into smtp@Mail
( fromEmail
, toEmail
, subject
, body
, smtpHostAddress
, smtpUsername
, smtpPassword
)
VALUES
( "no_reply@XXX.com"
, "XXX@XX.com"
, "Test"
, "Body"
, "smtp.office365.com"
, "XXX@XXX.com"
, "*******"
)
```

This results in the following error:

```
Uitroep itgendhb077: Error in Invantive Data Hub.
The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM [DB6P191CA0024.EURP191.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]
```

The username/password is correct (checked that), is there a way to trigger Invantive Data Hub to use a secure connection?

I have used the smtp syntax from [this](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/sending-mail-all-your-employees-across-world-exact-online-leenders) LinkedIn post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending email from Invantive SQL can sometimes be hard. In your case, I would recommend one of the following solutions:

- List your server which originates the SMTP request as a trusted address in Exchange for relaying messages outside your local network (when allowed to configure that) and allow (transport unsecured) SMTP port 25 connections.
- Or use a secured exchange.

The first one is a system administrator task; the use of secured transport can be enforced by specifying a value for the field `enableSsl` in `smtp@mail`.

This field `enableSsl` has become available in July 2017 and later releases. The full list of fields is:

- bccEmail
- body
- ccEmail
- fromEmail
- fromName
- headers
- isBodyHtml
- minimumDeliveryDurationMsec
- priority
- replyToEmail
- replyToName
- smtpHostAddress
- smtpHostPortNumber
- smtpPassword
- smtpUserName
- subject
- toEmail

### More Mail Fields

Please note that `insert into smtp@mail` has many more fields available, such as:

```
insert into Smtp@Mail 
(headers, fromEmail, fromName, replyToEmail, replyToName, toEmail, ccEmail, bccEmail, subject, body, isBodyHtml, priority, smtpHostAddress, smtpUsername, smtpPassword) 
values 
( 'X-SAMPLE:Y;X-SAMPLE2:Z'
, 'someone@somewhere'
, 'Test'
, 'me@home'
, 'Test'
, 'me@home'
, ''
, ''
, 'Ubersicht Rechnungen (HTML) [s-unittest]'
, '<p>Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren,</p>'
       || '<p>Um Ihnen unnötiges Nachhalten offener Rechnungen zu ersparen, informieren wir Sie mit diesem Schreiben über Ihr Konto bei ACME.</p>'
       || '<p>Wir wünschen Ihnen viel Erfolg bei Ihren Geschäften.</p>'
       || ' <p>Mit freundlichen Grüßen,</p>'
       || ' <p><b>Invantive GmbH</b></p>'
, 'true'
, -1
, 'smtp.server.address'
, 'some-user'
, 'some-password'
)
```

For instance, to include an attachment use the fields `attachmentContents`, `attachmentName` and `attachmentMimeType`. A full list of fields you get by querying either `systemtablecolumns@datadictionary` or pressing F4 in the query tool when the cursor is located on the `smtp@mail` text.

### Defaults

You don't have to specify all values on your `insert into smtp@mail`. There are a number of options for which you can set defaults from your settings.xml connection string or through the `set` statement.

The available options can be using a query like `select * from systemdatacontainerattributes@datadictionary` or on `systemproviderattributes`:

- `smtp-minimum-deliver-duration-ms`: Minimum deliver duration in milliseconds for the SMTP send plus inserted sleep when SMTP send finished earlier than the minimum.
- `smtp-send-timeout-ms`: Timeout in milliseconds after which the SMTP send times out.
- `smtp-enable-ssl`: Set whether SSL is enabled for SMTP connections.
- `smtp-password`: The default SMTP password to authenticate with.
- `smtp-user-name`: The default SMTP user name to authenticate with.
- `smtp-host-port-number`: The default SMTP host post number to use.
- `smtp-host-address`: The default SMTP host address to use.
- `mail-priority`: Priority of the mail; negative is bulk, 0 is neutral, positive is urgent.
- `mail-body-html`: Set whether the mail body is HTML.
- `mail-reply-to-name`: The default REPLY TO name.
- `mail-reply-to-email`: The default REPLY TO email address.
- `mail-from-name`: The default FROM name.
- `mail-from-email`: The default FROM email address.
- `pre-request-delay-ms`: Pre-request delay in milliseconds.
- `invantive-use-cache`: Whether to cache the results of a query.
- `invantive-sql-shuffle-fetch-results-data-containers`: Whether to shuffle results fetched from data containers.
- `invantive-sql-forward-filters-to-data-containers`: Whether to forward filters to data containers.

Comment: If i query the datadictonay I get the following result:

`bccEmail,
body, 
ccEmail, 
fromEmail, 
fromName, 
headers, 
isBodyHtml,
minimumDeliveryDurationMsec,
priority, replyToEmail, 
replyToName, 
smtpHostAddress, 
smtpHostPortNumber, 
smtpPassword, 
smtpUserName, 
subject, 
toEmail`

and if I use it in the insert query I get the following error: `Exclamation itgendid152: Missing metadata for column 'enableSsl'.`

Comment: stable-20170517348

Comment: I think it is not present in that release. Better upgrade to a more recent version, I think july or later 2017.